# Update input with ng-model and ng-value and vice versa

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to make a form doing some simple multiplication and subtracting and wanted to use the angularJS data binding, but it is not working as expected.

I think can boil the problem or what I'm trying to achieve in this example:

```
<div ng-controller="myCont">
  <input  type="number" ng-model="form.val1" ng-value="form.val2" />
  <input  type="number" ng-model="form.val2" ng-value="form.val1" />
</div>
```

I was expecting the input fields to update each other, but they don't. If I enter a number in `form.val1` it updates itself and `form.val2`, but if I then do the same with `form.val2` the binding is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple F to C and C to F converter:

Just in HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="f" ng-change="c=(f-32)*5/9">
<input type="number" ng-model="c" ng-change="f=c*9/5 + 32">
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your suggestion But isn't it more of a workaround than using data binding? As you showed it can be done programmatically but this I hope to avoid.

Comment: @on_the_way_togetting_better I simplified the code for you